# Printing out elements of a linked list in reverse

Tags: java, singly-linked-list

I am practicing my data structures and trying out [this problem on HackerRank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/print-the-elements-of-a-linked-list-in-reverse/problem?isFullScreen=true) on printing the element of a linked list in reverse order.

I have looked through my solutions multiple times but I don't understand why it is wrong.

My Solution:

```
    static void reversePrint(SinglyLinkedListNode head) {
        if (head==null){
            return;
        }

        ArrayList<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<>();

        while(head!=null){
            intList.add(head.data);
            head = head.next;
        }

         Collections.sort(intList, Collections.reverseOrder());
        for(int i: intList){
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
```

Appreciate if someone can assist on pointing out my mistakes.

Comment: I can't see whatever is on the link because I'd have to register there.

Comment: `Collections.sort(intList, Collections.reverseOrder());`, you're sorting the list in reverse order, but are you sure it is already sorted in ascending order, so this approach works?

Comment: `Collections.sort(intList, Collections.reverseOrder())` is sorting by the natural order of the Integers in reverse, and not by its position on the list.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Stack` rather than `ArrayList`

```
static void reversePrint(SinglyLinkedListNode head) {
    if (head==null){
        return;
    }

    Deque<Object> intList = new ArrayDeque<>();
    while(head!=null){
        intList.push(head.data);
        head = head.next;
    }

    while(!intList.isEmpty()){
        System.out.println(intList.pop());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Appreciate if someone can assist on pointing out my mistakes

**The Problem**

You used an `ArrayList` whose behavior is [**F**irst **I**n **F**irst **O**ut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO_(computing_and_electronics)), so the order of the elements printed when you `for`-loop the `intList` is the same as the order in the linked list, starting from `head`.

**Possible solutions**

To fix your approach, you could simply:

1- Insert each element always in the position zero of `intList` using [List#add(int index, E element)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add-int-E-):

```
// ...
intList.add(0, head.data);
// ...
```

2- Or, you can replace the data structure you used to "revert" the elements.

For example, you can use any of the [**L**ast **I**n **F**irst **O**ut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LIFO_(computing)) data structures, such as [`Queue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) or [`Deque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) in their LIFO variant.

---

**Another alternative**

Giving you another completely different solution, you could implement it in a recursive manner like this:

```
static void reversePrint(SinglyLinkedListNode head) {
    if (head != null) {
        reversePrint(head.next);
        System.out.println(head.data);
    }
}
```

If `head` is `null`, do not print anything. Otherwise, first `reversePrint` the `next` element and after that, the current one (`head.data`)... this will cause the reversal effect.

It's worth noting that this doesn't reverse the order of elements, that is, it doesn't modify the `next` of each element.